# Jquery FadeIn FadeOut Loop Animation Overlaps

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, animation

I have used jquery fadein fadeout animation for 3 different sentences. Link is here paris.kanakia.com/zisit/ In this animation the "Z" is silent. But there is jerk and not consistency in the animation. Please find my code below.

```
function startAnim(){
setInterval(function () {
 $('#slide1').hide();
 $('#slide2').show();
 $('#slide2 .one').fadeIn(1000,function(){
                  $('#slide2 .one').fadeOut(1000,function(){
                   $('#slide2 .two').fadeIn(1000,function(){
                      $('#slide2 .two').fadeOut(1000,function(){
                          $('#slide2 .three').fadeIn(1000,function(){
                            $('#slide2 .three').fadeOut(1000);
                          });
                      });
                   });
                  });
                });
}, 8600);                    
}
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  startAnim();
});
```

Comment: what is your error can you provide fiddle

Comment: though the issue is not exactly clear, one thing to note is that you can't animate `display` from `block` to `none` or vice versa. Don't you think using jQuery's `fadeIn/fadeOut` methods would be much cleaner and readable?

Comment: @Atula i have mentioned the url above.. paris.kanakia.com/zisit/

Comment: @Mike now i have used fadein and fadeout but now i want smoothness in animation , what to do , the code is updated here paris.kanakia.com/zisit/

Comment: whether you use animate or fadeIn/fadeOut, I don't think smoothness will be affected. A better option would be to use css animation. You can easily implement that in this case and it will be much better, smoother and modifiable.

Comment: i have used following script but fade in and out is not smoother 
$('#slide2 .one').fadeIn(1000,function(){
     $('#slide2 .one').fadeOut(1000,function(){
            $('#slide2 .two').fadeIn(1000,function(){
                   $('#slide2 .two').fadeOut(1000,function(){
                              $('#slide2 .three').fadeIn(1000,function(){
                                $('#slide2 .three').fadeOut(1000);
                              });
                          });
                       });
                      });
                    });
http://paris.kanakia.com/zisit/index5.html

Comment: its paris.kanakia.com/zisit/  now